# How to implement "zebra striping" in highcharts axes

Tags: javascript, highcharts, zebra-striping

I want to implement "[zebra stripes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_striping_(computer_graphics))" styling on the highcharts background as it will in improving readability of the graph data.

Notice the gray color between horizontal axes
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6frYR.png

I was unable to find any such option in the highcharts website. It would be really helpful if someone had implemented it using custom javascript functions.

Comment: jquery will make it a lot easier.

Comment: So the background needs to be a zebra? If yes, you can prepare it as image and set it by parameter: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.plotBackgroundImage

Comment: Wouldn't the built in 'alternateGridColor' property be a whole lot easier than a background image? Especially since you'd have to adjust your image every time the axis extremes or intervals change...

Comment: @jlbriggs you are right, but I attached additional solution. I think that many variations are useful ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [`alternateGridColor`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.alternateGridColor). This will specify a color for the alternating category grids.